# How to get current user logged in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

In my project, when user login, I had use

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

and in I need get current logged in user to get user's role.
 I don't know how to do that. 
Any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller/action you can access this member variable to get the name

```
var x=HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

I use this name to then look up and see if they are in role, depending on how you have implemented the Identity part and if you have a role provider you can also do things like this

```
var isAdmin=HttpContext.User.IsInRole("administrator");
```